# COUNT(*) returns less number of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

I have view that returns 5167 rows when doing

```
SELECT * FROM MY_VIEW -- returns 5167 rows
```

But, if I do the `COUNT(*)` on that, I get a totally different number

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MY_VIEW -- returns 3112 rows
```

I've tried `EXEC sp_refreshview 'MY_VIEW'` but still keep getting above results.

I thought `COUNT(*)` is supposed to return a full row count (not filter out any null content as its not being executed for a column and thus should match number of rows returned using `SELECT *`

Any reason why that could be different?

I am using SQL Server 2012

** **Updating with more info based on comments** **

Did the following as mentioned in the comments

- I modified the command to reflect server name and DB name.
- confirmed that they are running in the same SSMS tab.
- Added schema name 'dbo.MY_VIEW' to the query
- Ran 'sp_updatestats'

Queries thus run in the SSMS tab are -

```
select @@SERVERNAME, DB_NAME(), count(*) from dbo.MY_VIEW; 
-- returns 3112

select @@SERVERNAME, DB_NAME(), * from dbo.MY_VIEW; 
-- returns 5167 rows in results

select @@SERVERNAME, DB_NAME(), *, COUNT(*) over () cnt FROM dbo.MY_VIEW; 
-- returns 5167 rows in results and 5167 as the count
```

** **Update 2** **

I found that if I run the `COUNT('column_1')`, then I get the result 3112, but if I do the `COUNT('any_other_column')`, am getting 5167! I checked and there are no  `NULL`s in column_1. Also, `COUNT(*)` should count the NULL's anyways and should not be focussed on a column, but should count the number of rows. So, fail to further understand any of the above results.

Comment: do you have a primary key on this table?

Comment: @sppcc42 can you replicate this in some small dummy data set? If so, can you please post it on sqlfiddle or the like and share it here?

Comment: Did you figure this out yet?

Comment: Without actual execution plans for the various cases this question is not answerable